# Load CKeditor with Simplified Toolbar on dynamically created page element

Tags: 6, wysiwyg

Drupal 6
ckeditor 3.6.4

I have page that loads the text area dynamically, so I am using

```
  CKEDITOR.replace('textarea-id');
```

Which works, but it is bringing in the full toolbar. I would prefer that the simplified toolbar is used, but it would also be acceptable to use the toolbar I have defined if loading the simplified is not possible. Least desirable would be to hard-code the toolbar, but I consider that a last resort. How do I accomplish this?

I have tried

```
 CKEDITOR.replace('textarea-id',
    {
        toolbar : 'myprofile'
    });
```

Which throws  js error:
Type x is undefined
, I think related to the fact that it cant load the profile. Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For better or worse, this is how I did it:

http://joe-riggs.com/blog/2012/11/drupal-ckeditor-load-configuration-settings-on-dynamic-page/

Comment: Just this one line works for me: **CKEDITOR.replace('textarea-id');**

Comment: That worked for me too, in the since that it would load a ckeditor on the text area. The problem was that it would always load the 'Default' toolbar and the not the custom one I defined along with my plugins. 

I was able to inspect the ckeditor javascript objects and I could see that my defined profile was not instantiated. I feel like there could have been a better way to do it within ckeditor but I couldn't figure out how.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example to load custom buttons in the Ckeditor toolbar:

```
CKEDITOR.replace('textarea-id');

CKEDITOR.config.toolbar = [
   ['Bold','Italic','Underline','SpellChecker','TextColor','BGColor','Undo','Redo','Link','Unlink','-','Format'],
   '/',   ['NumberedList','BulletedList','JustifyLeft','JustifyCenter','JustifyRight','Font','FontSize'],
    ] ;
```

Comment: The whole point was to use a profile that I had saved in the admin panel. I suppose if you want to modify the code every time you add a button or plugin, then this would work too